# Do we need to handle content providers related stuffs while orientation changes if used in Activity?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Although , I have gone through the article in developer site about handling of  orientation  changes

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/run time-changes.html

While there are many things described here like handling of Activity UI state ,fragments UI state ,
 I could not find anything about handling of content providers:

Do we  need to handle anything in respect to content providers if we are using content provider to update some widget in UI .Does the android system handles it or we should handle such cases manually .

Example : Suppose we have an activity and we are using content provider to fetch some data to show in list view .Now while content provider is fetching the cursor  and extracting the data from cursor to update the UI screen ,orientation change occurs.

**Note**: I know we have to handle threads manually in case of orientation change occurs if we have started threads from our Activity screen as activity instance will be killed but thread may alive and might through NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Loaders handle it for you since they don't have the same lifecycle as an activity/fragment. When you initialize a loader in an activity, if it already exists, it will be used.